# Good Android app for mutual fund research?

Tags: mutual-funds, research

I'm trying to compare several mutual fund options offered by my HSA account. I cannot seem to find a good mobile app that will allow me to enter the symbol and list historical performance as well as the risk information.

Can someone please suggest some good mobile app that will show 1yr yield, 5 year yield, risk factor etc?

Comment: So far fidelity seems the most closed application i found, but when i want to view performance information, it still takes me to desktop website

Comment: Why would you do it on your phone? Is it not something you cannot wait to do till you're in front of a computer?

Comment: @littleadv Well, maybe it's just me, but I found I'm with my phone much longer than in front of a computer. If while i have my phone and I can still so some research, that would be great.

Comment: The question implies that it is impractical to invest in such an application for a data provider. A lot of work for a small amount of users with almost zero ad click-through. Its not "angry bird" where they can sell you stuff inside the app...

Answer (score 1):

I find [Bloomberg App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bloomberg.android) to be the best research tool on cell phones. Easily you can get trends of target funds, find common metrics on that fund and can quickly glance over other funds in comparison. It also syncs directly with the web app and its totally free.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Microsoft's [MSN Money](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.amp.apps.bingfinance).

The interface is really clean and easy on the eye. It provides plenty of info on the funds, including main assets in the portfolio, the weight of assets by kind and by sector, as well as investment style.

Upon installation it prompts the use to use a localised and regionally adapted version, which is a nice plus.

I am very happy with it.